# BJT (Common-Collector Configuration)

Tags: transistors, bjt, configuration, common-collector

As we know that for the transistor to operate in the active mode, it should have emitter-base junction as **forward bias** and collector base junction as **reverse bias**. So the **common-collector configuration** should also follow the same rule. Below is a diagram:- 
[image]

In the above diagram we can see that Emitter base junction is forward-biased since **|Vee|>|Vbb|**, that's fine. But you can see that the base collector junction is also forward-biased (where it should be reverse-biased if it is in active mode) in both pnp and npn transistors. Please help me here, it has been a confusion for me since 1 month. I really want to understand it here. Please give me a descriptive answer.

Answer (score 1):

The diagram you found is just plain wrong. But it's difficult to reason about because it's drawn upside down compared to how we usually draw circuit diagrams. Once you are used to the usual circuit conventions it is much easier to understand a schematic drawn with higher potential nodes near the top and lower potential nodes near the bottom of the drawing.

Here's a typical common collector circuit with an NPN transistor, drawn "right-side up":

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUV4nB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've chosen arbitrary voltage values, but you are correct to say that the collector must be biased higher than the base, not lower. Similarly, the emitter will end up biased slightly lower than the base.

Comment: Its from the book Boylestad and Nashelsky 10th Edition.

Comment: I don't know what to say to that except even textbooks can have mistakes.

Comment: Looking at the [online text](http://www.academia.edu/8106168/Electronic_Devices_and_Circuits_RL_Boylestad_and_Louis_Nashelsky) it doesn't look to me like they spent much effort on the section (p. 127) where that diagram is used.

Comment: @Photon, they have just drawn the voltage polarities according to dirn. of current. I mean Ie, Ib and Ic. The trick has worked in all cases. But only here is the problem in CC configuration.

Comment: This diagram is wrong. I have not looked at all the other diagrams in the book to see if they are right or wrong.

Comment: I think they tried to copy the diagram from the common-emitter section to use in the common collector section, and didn't make all the necessary changes. The whole section is kind of bad, just saying "common collector is kind of like common emitter but not the same" without giving a real clear explanation of how or why. I'd find another book to read about common collector circuits (or go to the section about the "emitter follower" which is another name for the exact same circuit).

Comment: Yes, emitter follower is the same thing. I understand that. But can you give me an online link for CC Configuration so that you can validate what you are saying.

Comment: @John, you said it in your question post: "emitter-base junction as forward bias and collector base junction as reverse bias." this is entirely correct and the text book just made a mistake in this diagram.

Comment: Ok, I know. But everywhere I see online I get the incorrect image. Please show me a right image mate.

Comment: I included a schematic in my answer

Comment: Is it made by you or you have downloaded it?

Comment: I made it with the built in schematic editor.

Comment: See the problem is that in every text I have read I have found the same config. as image. I want an online image.

Comment: @JohnCena, if you want answers from other websites, you should ask your questions on other websites.

Comment: Ok. No offence. But when I googled it I saw the same image as mentioned in my image atleast 10 images. I am really confused.

Comment: What terms did you google?

Comment: Common Collector Configuration of BJT.